# How to show detail in table view on xcode

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

How can I create 10 rows in a table view on `xcode` and show a detail as alert when I click on them?

Comment: This is a good tutorial [populate uitableview](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-create-and-populate-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write Logic in `didselectRowAtIndexPath` Method

arr is `NSMutablearray`..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Detail"
                              message:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```